# If $n$ is any positive integer whose last digit is $5$, then $5$ divides $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Prove that if n is any positive integer whose last digit is a 5, then 5|n

Therefore, n is going to be 5, 15, 25, 35 etc ...

b∣a states that 'b divides a' and we know that 5∣5, 5∣15, 5∣25, 5∣35 ...

If I define my argument as, n = 5e then n/5 = e

*n = 5e*

5 = 5*1, 15 = 5*3, 25 = 5*5

*n/5 = e*

5/5 = 1, 15/5 = 3, 25/5 = 5

Is this all that is required to prove this statement as true?

Comment: You have proven that $5$, $15$, and $25$ are divisible by $5$. However, that does not cover all positive integers whose last digit is a $5$.

Comment: Write $n=a_k10^k+\cdots+a_1 10+5$. Profit.

Comment: Even easier $n=10k+5$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 1):

You have proven that $5$, $15$, and $25$ are divisible by $5$. However, that does not cover all positive integers whose last digit is a $5$.

**Hint**: If the last digit of $n$ is $5$ then we can write $n = 10m+5$ for some non-negative integer $m$. Can you show that $n = 10m+5$ is divisible by $5$ no matter what integer $m$ is?

Comment: Would I just write that statement and provide a few examples where e.g. m is -2, - 1, 0, 1, 2 ...

Comment: "Proof by example" is NOT a proof.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but how would I go about proving it then?

Comment: Treat $m$ as a variable. Can you show that $5$ is a divisor of $n = 10m+5$, i.e. that $\dfrac{n}{5} = \dfrac{10m+5}{5}$ is an integer for any integer $m$?